# ¿Hay alguna forma de restringir el acceso a ciertos métodos sin modificar la clase original?

Tags: java, nashnorn

Tengo la siguiente clase en Java:

**MyClass.java**

```
public class MyClass{
    public void metodo(){
       System.out.println("hola mundo");
    }

    public void metodoInseguro(){
        System.out.println("inseguro");
    }
}
```

**Main.java**

```
public class Main{
    static public void main(String[] args){
        ScriptEngine js = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("javascript");

        Bindings bindings = js.createBindings();
        bindings.put("MyClass", MyClass.class)
        js.setBindings(bindings, ScriptContext.ENGINE_SCOPE);

        js.eval("new MyClass().metodoInseguro()")
    }
}
```

Lo que quiero hacer es crear un wrapper o envoltura alrededor de esta clase o su instancia para que no se pueda acceder al metodo `metodoInseguro` desde el motor de javascript.

**Lo que consideré o intenté**

- Debido a que la clase es usada en varios lugares, no puedo modificarla "in-place"
- No me es una opción crear una subclase de MyClass, ya que creo la instancia a traves de un método y no tengo acceso a dicho. La instancia puede ser de cualquier subclase de MyClass.
- Se que puedo crear una clase nueva, pero eso implica reescribir todos los métodos, uno por uno (la clase a la que quiero aplicarle esto tiene muchos más metodos).
- Revisé la [documentación de ScriptEngine](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.scripting/javax/script/ScriptEngine.html).

**Nota** El motor de javascript que uso (ya no viene incluido en java) es [nashorn](https://central.sonatype.com/artifact/org.openjdk.nashorn/nashorn-core/15.1.1?smo=true)

¿Cómo podría hacerlo?